# Could 'Match' & 'March' be searched using wildcard character as "Ma*ch" or "Ma?ch" in indexing service?

Tags: sql, search, wildcard

I want wildcard character to search Match & March at the same time in indexing service. I am trying it with following query:

```
Select DocTitle,Filename,Size,PATH,URL,Directory 
from Scope() 
WHERE CONTAINS('"Ma*ch"')
```

Or

```
Select DocTitle,Filename,Size,PATH,URL,Directory 
from Scope() 
WHERE CONTAINS('"Ma?ch"')
```

But I am not getting any response as I think it tries to find Ma*ch as the complete word.

When I use * at the end of any prefix then it works fine, but I need it in middle of a word.
"Search is being done through documents not from database."

Answer (score 0):

I think correct syntax of contains is

> `contains (<column Name>,<Search Condition>)`

Comment: Do you think would this syntax work? We don't have columns in documents. Its for searching from documents not from database.